# SQL Using two tables for a query

Tags: sql

I'm learning SQL for a while and I'm stuck with this problem.

I have two tables for a storage company.
In one table for the bookings for the whole company consisting booking no., date, product nr., quantity and storage room.

And in one table I have storage facility name and storage rooms to define the room belong to which facility

I want to have the sum of the quantity of one specific product in one specific storage facility

```
SELECT sum(Quantity) from Bookings where ProductNo=8888 and Storage.StorageFacility="Central"
```

Do I have to use a more complex query for the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your storage facility is in a different table than the `BOOKINGS` table (and they are related via `STORAGE_ROOM`). So you need to [join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) these tables:

```
select sum(Quantity)
  from bookings b 
  join storage_facility_details sfd 
    on b.storage_room = sfd.storage_room
 where sfd.storage_facility = 'x'
   and bookings.productno='8888'
```

Comment: You are missing ProductNo, just put another "and" at the end: and b.ProductNo=8888

Comment: @DRAX yes, I'd missed it. But you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of SQL can be slightly different on different database systems. Usually quotes (`"`) are used to refer to tables and similar objects. Use single quotes (`'`) to give values. Also, all the tables that you refer columns of need to appear after `FROM`. If the columns `quantity` and `storagefacility` appear in both tables you need to fully quality the name.

Also you need to join the two tables on a column, so the `productno` must also be present in your `storage` table.

```
SELECT sum(quantity) FROM bookings, storage
   WHERE (bookings.productno = storage.productno)
         AND
         (bookings.productno='8888' AND storage.storagefacility='Central');
```